# How to correct Phonegap Buil error when uploading to IOS Connect : ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path

Tags: ios, phonegap-build

I have been trying to get an ipa file uploaded to Apple Connect to test it.

It is generated by Phonegap build, for App ID 3729636.

I am using a service to upload, since I don't have a MAC.

The error is the following : ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon20x20'"

[The icon files are as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMHvD.jpg)

The ios icon and screen configuration file excerpt is :

```
<platform name="ios">
<!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
<!-- iPhone 6 Plus -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
<!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
<!-- Spotlight Icon -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
<!-- iOS 6.1 -->
<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
<!-- iPad Pro -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-167.png" width="167" height="167" />
<!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87" />
<!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
<!-- iPad Pro -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167" />
<!-- Was missing -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-20.png" width="20" height="20" />

<splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
<splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
<splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
<splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
<splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
<splash height="768" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
<splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
<splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
<splash height="960" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
<splash height="480" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
</platform>
```

I have tried many versions of the CLI, from 6.5.0 to 9.0.0, without much difference (only the 6.5.0 has a different error).

```
The latest is 9.0.0 : <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-9.0.0"/>
```

To make the build, I package the www directory and upload the resulting zip file.

Please, please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

After much effort debugging with confusing error messages, the problem appeared to be with the image files themselves. They were saved with GIMP and probably GIMP tried to be too clever or insert too much info. It offers a lot of options when exporting and probably one of them wasn't appreciated by Cordova.

I opened and saved all images with Paint and the problem went away.